# it is possible to install docker desktop on VMWARE ESXI?

Tags: docker, vmware, esxi

it is possible to install docker desktop on virtual machine (vmware) windows 10 on a VMWARE ESXI ?

i am trying to install desktop docker on my vmware virtual machine with windows 10.
I installed the wsl2 support but at the end of the installation docker crashes with the following error:
Docker desktop 4.0.1
Installation failed
Component CommunityIstaller.ServiceAction failed to start services: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

I have done several tests but I cannot avoid this crash in any way.
The Operating System is a build that meets the minimum requirements to install Docker.
However, I noticed that Hyper-V is not enabled in the windows features. can this be a problem?
I think maybe it's a grafted virtualization problem because I install docker inside a VM. it's possible?
How can I solve? (or do you think that i will fix this problem with linux virtual machines?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does your host machine have all the advanced flags for 'efficient' nested virtualization? I wouldnt really recommend a third layer install of docker (as the final container is then virtual , on paravirtual (wsl2) on virtual (HyperV), on virtual (Esxi). I heavily assume the performance will be terrible.

And yes: You need Hyper-V, it's a requirement still. I assume, as you say its not available on the features, youre running a windows 10 home? Then sorry, you need at least Windows 10 Pro for Hyper-V support.

But as youre running a ESXI host, go the better performing way: Install any Linux distro of your choise, install docker there - if you wanna use it for Visual Studio etc. , you can still remotely debug etc. - and its performing better than on an a even deeper nested virtualized windows-wsl2. And btw: if its because of GUI, simply install the free Visual Studio Code, it offers Docker Tools which offer you many configiruation and monitoring options in a GUI , without enforcing you to do such a super deep nesting.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's definitely possible. I'd probably check the hardware assisted virtualization (if available) is [enabled](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-2A98801C-68E8-47AF-99ED-00C63E4857F6.html). If so, you might want to make sure you've satisfied the rest of the [requirements](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/#wsl-2-backend) for the WSL2 backend deployment. If you're still having issues, try an older version and try upgrading from there.

Answer (score 1):

Docker has the following documentation that [Docker containers can be installed inside VMWare ESXi](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/vm-vdi/).

I have successfully installed Docker inside a VMware Workstation 16.2.5 build-20904516 Windows 10 VM after following the answer to this [ServerFault question "https://superuser.com/questions/1578372/run-wsl2-inside-vmware-workstation-15"](https://superuser.com/questions/1578372/run-wsl2-inside-vmware-workstation-15) and then, in the Windows VM, [installing Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/).

Comment: I found the above question matched Docker's answer but did not try it.  The answer to MY question was running WSL2 in VMWare Workstation and was here: https://superuser.com/questions/1578372/run-wsl2-inside-vmware-workstation-15

Comment: I removed the equivocation, thanks.

Comment: This seems to me to be halfway between "Yes." and "See this link." - both of unconvincing helpfulness.

Comment: @Yunnosch, seems to me a pointer into the documentation with the answer is useful.

Comment: rfreytag, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Above is the canned comment for posts which only consist of links. Yours is "Yes + link" and very slightly better, but still... so short.

Comment: Does this work better @Yunnosch?

Comment: Again ever so slightly better. Now it is "Yes, I tried successfully, links (plural)." What you are still missing is at least a summary of the technical "How". What you provide is advertisment for "What" is found and achieved with what you link.